# Grouping web site users by routes they make

Tags: algorithm, web

I’m writing a simple website. I want to be able to group users by routes they make on my sites. For example I have this [site tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q28gg.jpg), but the final product will be more complicated. Lets say I have three users.

User one route is `A->B->C->D`

User two route is `A->B->C->E`

User three route is `J->K`

We can say that users one and two belongs to same group and user three belongs to some other group.

My question is: what algorithm or maybe more than one I should use to accomplish that> Also what data do I need to collect?

I have some ideas, however, I want to confront it with someone who might have more experience than me.

I’m looking for suggestions rather than an exact solution for my problem. Also, if there are any ready-made solution which I can read, I will appreciate it also.

Comment: If the initial part of the route is most important, all you need is that staple of CS: sorting.  If the final part is most important, reverse each list of visited sites before sorting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also consider common subpaths. A pointer in this direction and general web usage analysis is: http://pdf.aminer.org/000/473/298/improving_the_effectiveness_of_a_web_site_with_web_usage.pdf

Comment: Thanks this article is very interesting. It might be what i was looking for. If you have anything more i will really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

As a first cut, it seems reasonable to divide the problem into (1) defining a similarity score for two traces and (2) using the similarity scores to cluster. One possibility for (1) is [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance). Two possibilities for (2) are farthest-point clustering and k-modes.